# Issues when taking Dice one and Dice two with the same value and adding it to an integer

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am currently trying to get the number of times the two dice have identical values. This is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of rolls you want to do: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int r = scan.nextInt();
    final int FACES = 6, ROLLS = r;
    int [] rollCount = new int [FACES];
    int [] rolCount = new int [FACES];
    Die d1 = new Die();
    Die d2 = new Die();
    int myRoll = 0;
    int myRollTwo = 0;
    int Ident = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i <= 1)
    {
        int ii = 0;
        int iii = 0;
        for (ii = 1; ii <= ROLLS; ii++)
        {
            myRoll = d1.roll();
            rollCount[myRoll - 1]++;
        }

        for (ii = 1; ii <= ROLLS; ii++)
        {
            myRollTwo = d2.roll();
            rolCount[myRollTwo - 1]++;
            iii++;
        }
        if (myRoll == myRollTwo)
            {
                Ident++;
            }

        if (iii == ROLLS)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Die Number\tDie One\tDie Two\tTotal\t Amount of Identical Rolls");
    for (i = 0; i < rollCount.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + "\t\t\t" + rollCount[i] + "\t\t" + rolCount[i] + "\t\t" + ((rollCount[i] + rolCount[i])*(i + 1)) + "\t\t" + Ident);
    }
}
```

I know that the if statement near the end of the while loop wouldn't work because it would only do it once, so how exactly would I go about getting the number of times the two dice were the same?

Comment: The number of times `d1.roll()` matched `d2.roll()`? Start by using a single  `for` loop

Comment: Thank you, I honestly don't know how I didn't see that before, lol